# c# facebook access token

Tags: facebook

I receive an access token when a client allows my application on his facebook account. Based on that access token and an url I can print all his friends. I have a question: does this access token appears all the time the user logs in his application? i am asking this because the second time the user logs in in my application where i have a web browser the friend list doesn't pop up because the response from the site does not contain an access token anymore. where am i wrong? how can i check after the user accepts my app that he is online or loged in - if i want to prints his friends.

Comment: You have to send some money to zuckerberg to get a backdoor api for facebook. then you don't need any access token. :)

Comment: can you please tell me how many times should i receive the token acces ?

Comment: or can you answer to my question?:)

Answer (score 0):

First thing: sounds like you want to add the scope `offline_access` because what you are trying to do is really leveraging the FB authentication mechanism.

Also: It is probably easiest to use the FB Connect button and the JavaScript Client API, unless you intend on using the graph or REST API from a back-end server.

If you *ARE* intending to use back-end API integration read this paragraph: 
I have found it helps to ensure that you are using a proper authenticate URL (I use www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth but others have worked in the past..).  Just don't use an authorize only URL, or users will be forced to grant permissions repeatedly (never really understood that 'feature').  Next redirect the user to the URL with a request token, and keep your request secret on the server side (or well encrypted if on the client side).  After login, you receive the callback with an OAuth Verifier. Access verification URL graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token with the Verifier and you will receive the OAuth Access Token.  Save that token, as well as the user id.

As for checking that the current user is logged in, and/or has authorized your app and/or has friends using your app:

Have a look at FB Connect API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

call `FB.init` first, and then when you call `FB.getLoginStatus`, you will get an OAuth Token if the current user is logged in to FB and has previously authorized your app (either via the Connect Button or OAuth flow):

```
$wnd.FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session)
    var authToken = encodeURIComponent(response.session.access_token);
});
```

When executed in conjunction with the authenticate flow mentioned, users that have already authorized your application will get the same OAuth Access Token returned from previous calls, that you can use with the JS Client, Graph, or REST APIs.